# Change CSS locally per domain

Tags: html, css, browser, greasemonkey

I want to add CSS to pages with a certain URL in much the same way that [Greasemonkey](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greasemonkey) adds JavaScript. I guess I could inject some CSS with a script, but that isn't as clean.

Are there any browser plugins that let me do this? It doesn't necessarily need to be a Firefox one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have access to [jQuery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery), you could do this pretty easily:

```
var css_href = "path to css";
var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0]; 

$(document.createElement('link')) 
    .attr({ type: 'text/css', 
            href: css_href, 
            rel: 'stylesheet, 
            media: 'screen''}) 
    .appendTo(head);
```

[[Source]](http://groups.google.com/group/jquery-en/browse_thread/thread/3cb891c3f874fef0)

This can also be done pretty easily with vanilla JavaScript:

```
function addStyle(style) {
    var head = document.getElementsByTagName("HEA­D")[0];
    var ele = head.appendChild(window.document.c­reateElement( 'style' ));
    ele.innerHTML = style;
    return ele;
}

addStyle('@import "/URL/TO/STYLESHEET;"');
```

[[Source]](http://forums.whirlpool.net.au/forum-replies-archive.cfm/475147.html) (Apparently from "[Dive into Greasemonkey](http://web.archive.org/web/20110726001221/http://diveintogreasemonkey.org/)" by [Mark Pilgrim](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mark_Pilgrim_%28software_developer%29) originally)

You might want to make sure your styles have `!important` declarations though.

Having said that, it should be easy to remove the existing stylesheets this way too and perhaps even iterate elements and remove inline styles.

Comment: The plain js solution works well except the url to the style sheet has backslashes in it (windows style). These are stripped out. It's actually a samba drive, I don't like windows that much.

Comment: You can't escape them in? Alternatively why doesn't `file://drive:/folder/` work? Windows isn't typically slash sensitive, it just has a preferred presentation method.

Answer (score 4):

There's the [Stylish](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/2108/) add-on for Firefox. It supports global, per-domain, and per-URL user stylesheets. It seems to work well for what I use it for, although I admittedly haven't played around with it very seriously.

Comment: Not really what I wanted. I need to be able to use a file and edit that rather than copy and paste it into a form within the plugin.

Comment: why not store the css in a [gist](http://gist.github.com/) from which you transfer to [userstyles.org](http://userstyles.org/) or [stylish](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/2108/) directly?

If you're only adding css, then using a userstyle is a far better idea than using a userscript.